# Undefined offset ??? PHP my code attached

Tags: for-loop, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

i am getting "ranksection" array at run time and after implementing ksort on "ranksection" i wanna move its data upward on null index as i am printing ranksection before moving its data upward if there were any free array i am successfully getting what i want but it also giving error "Undefined Index" i dont know why my code is,

```
$sortvar = count($ranksection);
$seqnum = 0;

for ($var = 0; $var <= $sortvar; $var++) {
  if ($ranksection[$var] !=  null) {
    $sequence[$seqnum] = $ranksection[$var];
    $seqnum++;
  }
}

print_r($sortvar);
print_r($ranksection);
print_r($sequence);
```

the result is,

```
3

Array ( [1] => Self Introduction [2] => Experience in Econometrics and multivariate S [3] => Experience ) 

Array ( [0] => Self Introduction [1] => Experience in Econometrics and multivariate S [2] => Experience )
```

Hopes for your suggestions

Comment: This error occurs only if you try to access array element that doesnt exist. for example if $array has 3 elements, then if you try to access array element $array[3] and so on.

Comment: @Sabin array has 3 element so it will find it and the second thing is for loop it will not run after 3 index value

Comment: @SyedRaza, You have problem in here

for ($var = 0; $var <= $sortvar; $var++)

Should be

for ($var = 0; $var < $sortvar; $var++)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See your print_r section of second array it starts with index 1 and your $var assigned to 0.
Now here you are trying to access the 0th index. that is why you're getting this error.

Try to use `foreach`

```
foreach($ranksection as $key => $value ) {
  if ($ranksection[$key] !=  null) {
    $sequence[$seqnum] = $ranksection[$key];
    $seqnum++;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply it help me what is the line "foreach($ranksection as $key => $value )" doing actually ???

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Do this as the condition for your `for` loop:

```
for ($var = 0; $var <= $sortvar - 1; $var++) {
```

The `-1` is important since arrays start from 0 and go the length of the array, minus one.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be using `count()-1` in your `for` loop:

```
$sortvar = count($ranksection) -1;
$seqnum = 0;

for ($var = 0; $var <= $sortvar; $var++) {
```

Or, use less than (without less than equal to) as the operator:

```
for ($var = 0; $var < $sortvar; $var++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going past the end of your array because:

```
$sortvar = count($ranksection); // This is 4
```

Array indexs start at 0, but count returns the number where 1 is the first item, not 0. Do this to fix it:

```
$sortvar = count($ranksection) - 1;
```

Or change <= to <

```
for ($var = 0; $var < $sortvar; $var++) {   
    if ($ranksection[$var] !=  null) {   
          $sequence[$seqnum] = $ranksection[$var];   
          $seqnum++;   
    }   
}
```